# conversion from util.Date to sql.Date not working

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, java.util.date

Why does the below query return this error message: 'data exception: invalid datetime format'? I have researched this and there does not seem to be anything wrong with it?

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date(); 
releaseDate = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
qtd.updateTakenOutTable("insert into takenOutTbl (MovieID, CellPhoneNum, DateTakenOut) VALUES ( ?,      ?, ?)", movieID, num, releaseDate);
```

and here is the method:

```
public void updateTakenOutTable(String update, String movieID, String num, java.sql.Date releaseDate) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Connection connection = dc.DatabaseConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        statement.setString(1, movieID);
        statement.setDate(2,releaseDate);
        statement.setString(3, num);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        statement.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is qtd.updateTakenOutTable supposed to be doing? Is it expecting a sql.Date parameter? It might be wanting a string in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: Yes it is expecting a java.sql.Date parameter.

Comment: Where is the code where you declare your query parameters?

Comment: You are declaring your parameters in the wrong order. They need to be declared in the same order as they appear in the SQL statement.

Comment: I did do that but now I am receiving this error: 
integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10179 table: TAKENOUTTBL

Comment: That is a different problem.

Comment: You are right, with the help of @Robby Cornelissen it turned out to be that I was inserting a new record with the same primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are trying to assign `releaseDate` into *CellPhoneNum* and `num` to *DateTakenOut*.

try

```
statement.setString(2, num);    
statement.setDate(3,releaseDate);
```

Comment: Prima facie it looks like primary key violation. Check your table description to see what is this constraint about.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing how your date and time information is formatted, hence invalid formats... one is "long" and one is not.  Can't see the declared types if any.

**today** is a util.Date
see   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

> *long*     getTime()  Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT >represented by this Date object.

**releaseDate** is a sql.Date
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/class-use/Date.html#java.sql

Reading this documentation carefully, you will see that the type is NEVER represented as "long."

If you want a sql oriented time, perhaps you would rather use ... sql.time?  This has its own page on docs.oracle.

The sql.date and sql.time are intended for communicating with SQL databases, while the utility. Date is not. Time is not easily handled across different database systems.  The long type you referenced is to count milliseconds like a timer...this timer started in 1970 for the Y2K problem at the turn of the century. It allows comparison on this scale.  Note the documents regarding how many milliseconds are in various lengths of time ...

Comment: Lot's of good info here.  However, the answer to the question is that the parameters were declared in the wrong order.